# Creating an OR logic function with a list composed of bool functions Python

Tags: python, for-loop, math, boolean, logic

I want to write a function that checks if the `True` boolena statement is within `all_vals` if there is a `True` value then the code will `yes` if not the code will output `no`, essentially creating an or statement. The code below does not work how would I be able to modify it so that it will get the Expected output below?

```
def vals(all_vals):
    for x in all_vals:
        if True in all_vals:
            print('yes')
        else:
            print('no')


a = [True, True, True]
b = [True, False, True, True, False]
c = [False, False]
d = [True, False]

vals([a,b,c,d])
```

Expected Output:

```
yes
yes
no
yes
```

Comment: I think you want this line `if True in all_vals:` to be `if True in x:`

Comment: Note that `if True in x:` is almost equivalent to `if any(x):`. See [the documentation on builtin function `any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of: `if True in all_vals:` you need `if True in x:` like this:

```
def vals(all_vals):
    for x in all_vals:
        if True in x:
            print('yes')
        else:
            print('no')


a = [True, True, True]
b = [True, False, True, True, False]
c = [False, False]
d = [True, False]

vals([a,b,c,d])
```

Also you can shorten your code durastically by instead using:

```
vals = lambda all_vals: print("\n".join(['yes' if True in i else 'no' for i in all_vals]))

a = [True, True, True]
b = [True, False, True, True, False]
c = [False, False]
d = [True, False]

vals([a,b,c,d])
```

Output:

```
yes
yes
no
yes
```

Comment: Your suggestion to "shorten the code drastically" makes it much, much harder to read and understand. In addition, using a `lambda` to define a named function is against the style guide: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: @Stef I agree it is simply for those who enjoy one-liners. That is why I also gave the extended version.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def vals(all_vals):
    for x in all_vals:
        if True in x: # <--- Your typo here
            print("yes")
        else:
            print("no")


a = [True, True, True]
b = [True, False, True, True, False]
c = [False, False]
d = [True, False]

vals([a, b, c, d])
```